# What is "Forecasting the most probable following value"

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, prediction-interval

I am reading the book, "Machine Learning in Java" published by Packt publishing, and written by Boštjan Kaluža; and there is a paragraph at the book, and I can not understand.

At the book, there is a concrete dataset that comprises real traffic to Yahoo services, along with some synthetic data. Here is the snippet of the data:

[image: snippet of the synthetic time-series data]

The author wants to detect anormaly in this dataset, and he wrote the paragraph below:

> Detecting anomalies in raw, streaming time series data requires some
>   data transformations. The most obvious way is to select a time window
>   and sample time series with fixed length. In the next step, we want to
>   compare a new time series to our previously collected set to detect if
>   something is out of the ordinary.
>   The comparison can be done with various techniques, as follows:
>
>  Forecasting the most probable following value, as well as
>   confidence intervals (for example, Holt-Winters exponential
>   smoothing). If a new value is out of forecasted confidence interval,
>   it is considered anomalous.

He hasn't mentioned how to "forecast the most probable following value" afterwards. How can one do it in concrete terms?

Comment: The author misuses statistical terminology, which should cause us to wonder what he is actually trying to say (+1). Forecasting is a matter of producing *prediction intervals*, not "confidence intervals," and since his method is a *sequential* one, such prediction intervals will need to be (substantially) wider than prediction intervals based on analyzing just a single time series.

Comment: What is "prediction intervals"? How can I produce "prediction intervals" then?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prediction+interval%22

Comment: See reviews of this book at https://www.amazon.com/Machine-Learning-Java-Bostjan-Kaluza/dp/1784396583